# Is my Universal Analytics Event Tracking syntax correct?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, universal-analytics

What I've been doing:
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value)"

My biggest question is adding the **{'nonInteraction': 1}**

What I think I should be doing:
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', {'nonInteraction': 1} value)"

I'm not sure if I need more commas or '!

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make sure everything is passed correctly, I would use this syntax:

```
ga('set', 'nonInteraction', true);
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);
```

So with the onClick event, it would be:

```
onClick="ga('set', 'nonInteraction', true);ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);"
```

**Also, if you are sending event value, make sure it's an INTEGER. Otherwise, the event won't fire at all.**

Comment: Thank Petr - trying it now!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming with {'nonInteraction': 1}, you want to treat this event as a non-interactive event which does NOT affect bounce rate.  If you had {'nonInteraction': 0}, the user clicks the button/event item, and leaves the page, this would be considered a 0% bounce rate. Correct?